# I've build a drop down menu

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, menu

I'd like to make it disappear when clicking anywhere else on the screen - for some reason it's  doesn't work

Can anyone help resolve this!

Here's my script:

```
jQuery(function ($) 
{
    $('.dropdownlist-title .listbox').click(function () 
    {
        if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('active'))
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        else
            $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("*").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    if ($(".dropdownlist-title").hasClass('active')) {
        $(".dropdownlist-title").removeClass('active');
    } else {
        if ($(this).parents().hasClass('dropdownlist-title') || $(this).attr('class') == 'dropdownlist_title') {
            $(".dropdownlist-title").addClass('active');
        }
    }
});
```

. You select everything
. You stop the event propagation to avoid multiple invoks
. You close the dropdown if needed
. You open it only if the trigger (or some of its inner elements, such as the arrow) has been clicked

Working sample here:http://jsfiddle.net/lukame/usob50ex/embedded/result/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/swarupsrk/rbtvmbkt/embedded/result/                              please look this link .its not working

Comment: Here is a working example. I also modified the cose above. http://jsfiddle.net/lukame/usob50ex/embedded/result/